# Setting up SRV records for Minecraft with Cloudflare

Tags: dns, minecraft

I can't seem to be able to setup SRV records for my minecraft server on cloudflare. I have all my name servers right. I'll show a screenshot of what I'm doing

[image]

I have 2 records testing different domains and other things, test.warpedmc.com works on its own but the SRV does not.

Comment: Use Wireshark (or a similar tool) to check out what’s actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dig srv _minecraft._tcp.test2.warpedmc.com` shows me both records correctly.

Comment: Still wont allow me to connect through. Any ideas?